# For all integers $k$, $l$, $m$, $n$, if $k = nl + m$, then $n$ divides $k$ iff $n$ divides $m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I have attempted to use the division theorem, but I am unsure exactly where to begin. Any hints/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Proved as part of the proofs in the linked dupe. Said symmetrically $\bmod n\!:\ $ if $\,k\equiv m\,$ then $\,k\equiv 0\iff m\equiv 0\,$ follows immediately because cogruence is an *equivalence* relation.

Comment: It´s pretty easy, only you need use the definition.

Assume that $k=nl+m$ and that $n|k$, then by definition $k=nq$ where $q\in \mathbb{Z}$
then $nq=nl+m \Rightarrow nq-nl=m \Rightarrow n(q-l)=m$ and then $n|m$

Can you take frome here

Comment: $k = n(l + \frac mn)$.  If $\frac mn$ is an integer then $n|k$.  And $\frac kn = l+\frac mn$.  If $\frac mn$ is not an integer then neither is $\frac kn$>

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, consider why

- if $n$ divides $m$ then $n$ divides $nl+m$
- if $n$ divides $k$ then $n$ divides $k-nl$

To make things even easier in the first case, if $n$ divides $m$ then $a=\frac mn$ is an integer and $m=na$, so the question becomes:  why if $n$ divides $m$ then $n$ divides $nl+na$?  Similarly with the second case.

Comment: Please strive not to post more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs

Answer (score 0):

Use the definitions directly:
$$
n \mid m 
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
m = nr \text{ for some } r \in \mathbb{Z}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
k = nl + nr = n(l + r) 
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
n \mid k
$$
since $l + r \in \mathbb{Z}$ if $l, r \in \mathbb{Z}$.

To prove the other direction, rewrite
$$
m = k - nl, 
$$
and argue in an analogous manner.

Comment: Please don't answer question closed as dupes (esp, when the answer is a dupe).